# First Tuesday of the month

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I would like to get the first Tuesday of the month. I am doing like this :

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *com = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|kCFCalendarUnitWeekday|NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal fromDate:today];
[com setWeekday:3];
[com setWeekdayOrdinal:1];

NSDate *firstTuesday = [calendar dateFromComponents:com];
NSLog(@"firstTuesday %@", firstTuesday);// firstTuesday 2015-10-22 22:00:00 +0000
```

Do you know what i am doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: it's not the same thing. The first was to "Test if a date is the first Tuesday of the month" the second question is "How to get the first Tuesday of the month as NSDate"

Comment: Apologies; misread that.

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it, this is the sample code :

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *todayCompoenents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear |NSCalendarUnitMonth  fromDate:today];

NSDateComponents *com = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[com setYear:[todayCompoenents year]];
[com setMonth:[todayCompoenents month]];
[com setWeekday:3];
[com setWeekdayOrdinal:1];

NSDate *firstTusday = [calendar dateFromComponents:com];
NSLog(@"firstTusday %@", firstTusday);
```